# how to organise favorites in Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is there an equivalent to Google Chrome's Bookmark Manager for Microsoft Edge Favorites?

I find the Favorites interface very inefficient for making large scale changes to Microsoft Edge Favorites.

I understand Edge stores may save its Favorites in: `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Favorites` but when I checked there this folder was empty.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That location is no longer being used by Edge.  Modern versions of Edge do not store favorites as files and folders like you've become accustomed to.  Instead, they are now stored in a database.

There is a free 3rd-party application called EdgeManage that can help you with managing your Edge favorites in a manner that should feel similar to Chrome's (or IE's) bookmark manager

Take a look at this article to see if this is something that you'd be interested in.

http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeManage.html

PS: I'm the author